# getting some strange error on html code inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I getting this error? Probably have to do something with the quotation marks?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is right, you can't span strings like this over many lines.

To keep this construct, add a `\` at end of line :

```
$('body').append("<div product id=product_header>\
    <table id=product_header_table>\
    </table>\
</div>")
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings can't span over many lines in javascript.  Since the line begins with `"` and does not end with `"`, its an error.

You can place a `\` at the end of each line, which escapes the newline.  If you do this, the dom you are appending will NOT have the pretty formatting it does in your code, since the newline is escaped.

The other option is to use a `+` to concatenate some strings together

```
$().append(
   "<dom>" +
   "<moredom>" +
   "<moredom>" 
);
```